# time varying event

Tags: regression, time-series

I am trying to model predictors of infections for a group of patients. The rates of infection vary by calendar time and so i was attempting to use a calendar time scale Cox model. However patients entered the study starting in 2022 and were observed until the the end of 2022. So some patients enter as late of april of 2022.

Given the staggered entry date and calendar time dependent outcome of interest, what options do i have for modeling the data? Could i change the outcome to a rate and use poisson regression?